# Compare two integers

Tags: php, integer, compare

How do you compare two integers in php?

I have tried

```
print (1 > 2);           // No output
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = ($a > $b) ? true : false;
print ($c);              // No output
```

var_dump works fine.
I have the latest PHP installed.

Comment: PHP's built-in REPL is very bad. I recommend you download some of the PHP REPL's from github.com

Comment: So `var_dump()` works but `print()` doesn't? Doesn't that suggest a problem with `print()` instead of in comparing the variables?

Comment: Also, `$foo ? true : false` is superfluous (it evaluates to `true` if the variable is `true` and `false` if it's `false`).

Comment: I was comparing two strings using php's similar_text($str1, $str2, $p). I was comparing $p to 70 to see if $p is greater than 70. Nothing was happening so I decided to print the comparison print ( $p > 70 ) and (now I know) php prints nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your comparisons return `false` which will not print out a value.

```
<?php
echo true;
echo false;
```

Answer (score 3):

`print(false)` will output nothing.

If you want to display `false`, try `var_export(false)`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print false in both cases which will by casted to an empty string, hence you are not seeing anything printed.

Try using [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump) instead or outputting a string with a proper control structure (i.e. if else)

Answer (score 3):

You can compare two variable(int,float,string) value in php using **Spaceship operator** (**New feature of php 7**)

- **Integers**
  echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
  echo 1 <=> 2; // -1
  echo 2 <=> 1; // 1
- **Floats**
  echo 1.5 <=> 1.5; // 0
  echo 1.5 <=> 2.5; // -1
  echo 2.5 <=> 1.5; // 1
- **Strings**
  echo "a" <=> "a"; // 0
  echo "a" <=> "b"; // -1
  echo "b" <=> "a"; // 1

Answer (score 0):

The comparisons in your example are working fine.  The issue is that when you print true or false values, they don't render anything.  Try something like this instead:

```
$ php -a
$ print (1 > 2) ? 'true' : 'false';
$ $a = 1;
$ $b = 2;
$ $c = ($a > $b) ? true : false;
$ print ($c) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($a > $b) ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use something like:

```
$c = $a > $b;
echo $c;
```

or use `var_dump()`